# how to use retrofit @Post to send this body to restApi server in kotlin :

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

body format , that I want to send to rest api server :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for sending nested json with retrofit , must use @Body annotation in api interface, for above JSON :

first make a data class for your hole JSON :

```
data class YourJSON (@SerializedName("data")
                      var data : String,

                    @SerializedName("data2")
                      var data2: Data2 ,

                    )
```

then make a data class for another object inside the JSON :

```
data class Data2 (@SerializedName("obj")
                  var obj: String,

                @SerializedName("obj1")
                  var obj1: String ,

                @SerializedName("obj2")
                  var obj2: String ,

                @SerializedName("obj3")
                  var obj3: Int

                )
```

then make an interface class :

```
interface ApiService {


@POST(/api/your/url)
  fun sendData(
    @Body  yourJson : YourJSON,
): Observable <yourResponse> }
```